# Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value uitextfield

Tags: ios, swift

I know there are a lot of unexpected nil value questions here, but I've tried other approaches and they're not working for me. The function at the bottom is called from a button on another view controller. Basically the issue is that this code works as expected, the form element has the DatePicker as the input view, and it updates startDatePickerField.text when the value is changed, so I know that startDatePickerField.text is not empty, as it is displayed on the screen. However, when calling the testForValidity() function is called from another view controller containing the one we are working in, I get the "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping option value error". All of the outlets are connected properly so I know it isn't that.

```
class popoverTableViewController: UITableViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet var startDatePickerField: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
let startDatePicker:UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()
    startDatePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.dateAndTime
    startDatePickerField.inputView = startDatePicker
    startDatePicker.minuteInterval = 5
    startDatePicker.addTarget(self, action:  #selector(popoverTableViewController.startDatePickerValueChanged(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged) 
}

    @IBAction func startDateDidBegin(_ sender: AnyObject) {
}

    func startDatePickerValueChanged(_ sender: UIDatePicker) {

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = DateFormatter.Style.long
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = DateFormatter.Style.short
    startDatePickerField.text = dateFormatter.string(from: sender.date)
    finishDateTime = sender.date

}
```

And the function that errors:

```
    func testForValidity() {

    print(startDatePickerField.text)

}
```

Comment: Where is testForValidity()? In popoverTableViewController? How are you calling it?

Comment: testForValidity() is in popoverTableViewController yes, it's a simple call from another class after pressing a button. I've realised that this method calls a new instance of my popoverTableViewController thats why I get the error. I think the fix has something to do with NSNotificationCentre, but I'm unsure of how to implement it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Issue:**

- You're trying to access IBOutlet property from another class via instance method.
- The reason behind the nil value is IBOutlets are initialized when the nib is loaded.

Hence in your case when you are in another view controller you can't access an Outlet variable else you will be always getting *nil*.

**Solution:**

If I assume correctly, you want to use a value from a view controller after having a value in it.

The best way is to follow '**Design patterns**'. i.e., You have to store your required value in a model class and access the value via model class instance.

Apple has very good documentation about it. Please go through.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson6.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH20-SW1

**Sample Code in Swift:**

```
class TextFieldViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var outputLabel : UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var textField : UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() { super.viewDidLoad(); setupTextField() }

    func testValidity() -> (textFieldValue: UITextField?, modelValue: String?) {
        return (textField, TextFieldModel.sharedModel.textFieldData)
    }

    //MARK: - Text Field Delegates
    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        outputLabel.text = textField.text
        TextFieldModel.sharedModel.textFieldData = textField.text
        return true
    }

}

class TextFieldModel {
    static let sharedModel = TextFieldModel()
    var textFieldData: String?
}

class DemoController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textFieldOutput: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var modelOutput: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() { super.viewDidLoad(); testValues() }

    func testValues() {
        let tvc = TextFieldViewController()
        textFieldOutput.text =  "Value of Text field is " + (tvc.testValidity().textFieldValue?.text ?? "nil")
        modelOutput.text = "Value accessed from Model Class is \(tvc.testValidity().modelValue)"
    }
}


extension TextFieldViewController {
    func setupTextField() {
        textField.placeholder = ""
        textField.delegate = self
        textField.becomeFirstResponder()
        textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.Default
        textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Done

    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much for taking the time to answer, works a charm!

Comment: You're welcome. Glad I can help you with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

At the top, add `UITextFieldDelegate` so it becomes:

```
class popoverTableViewController: UITableViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate {
```

Then in `viewDidLoad()` add this line :

```
self.startDatePickerField.delegate = self
```